# Print UTF-8 multibyte character in C

Tags: c, unicode

I wrote this code to print a UTF-8 multibyte string. But it does not print properly. Note: I am doing it in a Linux system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("\n locale =%s\n", locale);
    printf("test\n \x263a\x263b Hello from C\n", locale);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not UTF-8.  You might consider using the Unicode escape `\u`.

Comment: 1. `setlocale` is probably unnecessary. 2. UTF8 representation for [U+263A](https://unicode-table.com/ru/263A/) is `\xE2\x98\xBA`.

Comment: use `u8"\u263a\u263b"` instead

Comment: @phuclv, Is that a `gcc` extension? I had to use `-std=gnu99` with `gcc` for `u8"..."` to work. (`-std=c99` wasn't enough.)

Comment: @ikegami that's supported [since C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\u` instead of `\x`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("\n locale =%s\n", locale);
    printf("test\n \u263a\u263b Hello from C\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This runs and produces the following output:

```
$ gcc foo.c
$ ./a.out 

 locale =C
test
 ☺☻ Hello from C
```