# how do you print copyright symbol in C?

Tags: c, unicode

I am trying to print:

```
printf("rlstats (1.0.0), © 2020 name \nEnter a list of comma - separated real number pairs terminated by EOF or non numeric input.\n");
```

but the © isnt printing, how would I do about this? is there a code for it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58039815/1707353) will help.

Comment: Some authors simply output `Copyright (C) 2020` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using © directly, you should use the corresponding unicode `\u00A9`

Comment: printf("rlstats (1.0.0), \u00A9 2020 name\nEnter a list of comma - separated real number pairs terminated by EOF or non numeric input.\n"); did not work

Comment: Depending on the charset of your source code and of the console terminal, `\xA9` may work instead instead of `\u00A9`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `wprintf`:

```
wprintf(L"rlstats (1.0.0), © 2020 name\n");
wprintf(L"Enter a list of comma-separated real number pairs terminated by EOF or non-numeric input.\n");
```

Comment: I actually get `(C)` instead of `©` with this.

Comment: @dbush Weird. I get that too. [Asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458832/why-is-the-copyright-symbol-replaced-with-c-when-using-wprintf) about it.