# Why is © (the copyright symbol) replaced with (C) when using wprintf?

Tags: c, printf, widechar

When I try to print the copyright symbol `©` with `printf` or `write`, it works just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("©\n");
}
```

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    write(1, "©\n", 3);
}
```

Output:

```
©
```

But when I try to print it with `wprintf`, I get `(C)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    wprintf(L"©\n");
}
```

Output:

```
(C)
```

It's fixed when I add a call to `setlocale`, though:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wprintf(L"©\n");
}
```

Output:

```
©
```

Why is the original behavior present and why is it fixed when I call `setlocale`? Additionally, where does this conversion take place? And how can I make the behavior after `setlocale` the default?

compilation command:

```
gcc test.c
```

`locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`echo $LC_CTYPE`:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux penguin 4.19.79-07511-ge32b3719f26b #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 18 17:41:41 PST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`file test.c` (same on all of the examples):

```
test.c: C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

`gcc --version`:

```
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so` (`glibc` version):

```
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) stable release version 2.24, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 6.3.0 20170516.
Available extensions:
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

`cat /etc/debian_version`:

```
9.12
```

Comment: One https://ideone.com/LMOH1T Two https://ideone.com/D6D17k

Comment: It's translated by glibc autogenerated from [glibc/C-translit.h.in](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/locale/C-translit.h.in#L23).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The locale of the calling processes is not automatically inherited by the new process.

When the program first starts up, it is in the C locale.  The [man page for `setlocale(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) says the following:

> On startup of the main program, the portable "C" locale is selected
>   as default. A program may be made portable to all locales by calling:
>
> ```
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The locale "C" or "POSIX" is a portable locale; its LC_CTYPE part corresponds to the 7-bit ASCII character set.

So any multibyte / non-ASCII character is converted into one or more ASCII characters as the output shows.

The locale can be set as follows:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

The `LC_ALL` flag specifies changing all locale-related variables.  An empty string for the locale means to set the locale according to the relevant environment variables.  Once this is done, you should see the characters for your shell's locale.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    char *before = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    char *after = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);

    wprintf(L"before locale: %s\n", before);
    wprintf(L"after locale: %s\n", after);
    wprintf(L"©\n");
    wprintf(L"\u00A9\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
before locale: C
after locale: en_US.utf8
©
©
```